# SQL_Variant or separated data type value in EAV?

Tags: entity-attribute-value, sql-variant

We use `sql_variant` data type for value in EAV, but I think it's better that we use one table for each data type value because `sql_variant` is 8000 byte and I'm worried about this data type for huge value.

What's your idea? Which them is better?

ThanX

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is quite old but I thought I'd answer it anyway.

`SQL_VARIANT` does NOT use 8000 bytes for every row.  It uses the same number of bytes as the "base data type" + up to 16 bytes to store the meta-data for the entry.  It works fine for most EAV's and has the added advantage of preserving the original datatype.  It's also pretty fast especially on inserts because you don't have to convert to `VARCHAR`.

The real problem isn't whether or not to use `SQL_Variant` in an EAV... the real problem may be the reason why you're using an EAV to begin with.  ;-)